# Call to undefined function imageantialias()

Tags: php

**GD自体は動作しているのですが、使用できない関数があります**
・PHPを再ビルドすることなく、エクステンションか何かの方法で使えるようにする方法はないでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756144
によると `bundled gd` を有効にしないと `imageantialias` は使えない様子。
ウチの [php](/questions/tagged/php) `5.4.15` においては `bundled gd` 有効で `imageantialias` 呼べました。

エクステンションで何とかなったとして、それは [php](/questions/tagged/php) の推奨する正規の手順ではなさそうです。
サポートされない使い方をしてトラブルが発生したら自己責任ってのがこの業界の鉄則でしょう。
トータルでかかるコストは、今ちょっと手間をとっても再ビルドするほうが安いような気がします。